# How to include "regular" covariates in the estimation equation with conditional parallel trends assumption, on which trends should not be conditioned?

Tags: r

I use the `did` package that allows the inclusion of conditional parallel trends according to Callaway and Sant'Anna (2021, Journal of Econometrics). I am trying to find out how to include "normal" covariates, on which trends should not be conditioned.

The function I use is

```
att_gt(y_name = outcome_var, tname = year, idname = treatment_group, gname = first.treat, xformla = ~ conditional_vars, allow_unbalanced_panel = T, clustervars = clusters, data = data)
```

What I am looking for is an argument like `covariates = covariates`, which are not the `conditional_vars`, in the propensity score model, but just "regular" covariates as in `lm(outcome_var ~ covariate_1 + covariate_2)`.

Any inputs on that? I worry if I specify `est_method =` my own function, that then the estimation method is no longer the doubly-robust default.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: No, unfortunetaly not.